# How can I convert React code to ClojureScript one?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript

Here is the code I want to convert into ClojureScript:

```js
<Table
  onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
    return {
      onClick: (event) => {},
      onDoubleClick: (event) => {},
    };
  }}
....
```

I need to be able to provide multiple events on Table (***onRow***) component but could not find a way to convert this code into ClojureScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onRow` seems expect a "factory" function which returns the actual event handlers.

```clj
(defn on-row-factory [record row-index]
  #js {:onClick (fn [event] ...)
       :onDoubleClick (fn [event] ...)})

;; reagent

[:> Table {:onRow on-row-factory} ...]
```

You don't need to use the `defn` and could just inline a `fn` instead.

Comment: "could just inline a fn instead." - 
Wouldn't you get extra re-renders since you'd be passing down a new closure every time?

Comment: Yes, the JSX example does it as well though so the library probably expects it?